# Using database entries for if statements in php

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I am generating an excel file of database values. My database table consists a total of 6 values. Here there are three inputs:

```
Subject_1
Subject_2
Subject_3
```

which have values as Maths, Physics and Chemistry, and there are three results:

```
Result_P
Result_F
Result_N
```

which have values as Pass, Fail and Unknown.

Now my excel php looks like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
}

$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', '', '', ''); //my db values
$output ='';

{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Data ORDER BY ID DESC";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
    {
        $output .= '
        <table class = "table" bordered = "1">
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Subject 1</th>
                <th>Subject 1 Result</th>
                <th>Subject 2</th>
                <th>Subject 2 Result</th>
                <th>Subject 3</th>
                <th>Subject 3 Result</th>
            </tr>       
        ';
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $output .= '
            <tr>
                <th>'.$row["ID"].'</th>
                <th>'.$row["Subject_1"].'</th>
                <th>'.$row["Result_P"].'</th> //if marks of subject 1 scored more than 50
                <th>'.$row["Subject_2"].'</th>
                <th>'.$row["Result_F"].'</th> //if marks of subject 2 scored less than 50
                <th>'.$row["Subject_3"].'</th>
                <th>'.$row["Result_N"].'</th> //if marks of subject 3 is 0
           </tr>
            ';
        }

        $output .= '</table>';
        $fileName = "Excel_".date('Y_m_d').".xls";
        header("Content-Type: application/xls");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$fileName");
        echo $output;

}
?>
```

Now as you see I randomly assigned Result_P, Result_F and Result_N to each of these subjects. But this should not be random. That is, I want to create a function to check which result should belong to which subject based on an if statement?

So how do I assign the Result_P, Result_F and Result_N based on the marks obtained? I do not want to create new result entry in database for each subject, I want to reuse the 3 entries I created for Result.

Comment: First correct your `$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', '', 'DB', 'pass');` It is possible that parameter 3 might be blank but NOT parameter 2

Comment: Much more reliable to create a CSV file OR use [phpSpreadsheet](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to create the ouptut in real xlsx format than hoping a bit of html is going to be interpreted correctly into a speardsheet

Comment: If you are going to show us bits of a database it is far better to do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE YourTableName;` and copy/paste the output to your question or create us an SQLFiddle

Comment: Might be a good idea to look up the difference between `<th>` and `<td>`

Comment: There really should be a `pupil` table in here somewhere and a `pupil_subject` link and probably a `pupil_subject_result` table

Comment: @RiggsFolly Do you mean to say that I have to create a subject_result attribute for each of the subject?

Comment: I dont know enough about your system to design you DB for you, but you need to link people to subjects (I am taking Physics and Maths) and then People to their Subjects and the Results they got for each of those subjects (I got a P for Physics and a F for Maths)

Comment: Riggs means the pupil_subject table would have multiple rows per subject and pupil. E.g. the columns would be subjectID and pupilID, (each being a foreign key back the the "subjects" and "pupils" tables respectively) so for a pupil taking 3 subjects there would be 3 rows in that table. That means you don't need to have a separate attribute for each subject. Sounds like maybe you need to study the fundamentals of relational database design in a bit more detail.

Comment: P.s. `I am generating an excel file `...are you sure? Because it looks an awful lot like a HTML document to me. Excel uses a completely different format.